# PHP Attribute Class not found error when trying to get new instance from ReflectionAttribute

Tags: php, attributes, http-status-code-500, php-8.2

I have this Attribute that I have created to control access level into my route methods.

```php
namespace Lrc\Buscrawler\Attribute;

use Attribute;

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
class RouteAccess
{
    protected int $role;

    public const PUBLIC = 0;
    public const AUTHENTICATED = 1;
    public const ADMIN = 2;
    
    public function __construct($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function canAccess($sessionID)
    {
        error_log('Yes, you can.');
    }

}
```

This way I can put it into my controller methods to specify which role can access that route method, like this:

```php
namespace Lrc\Buscrawler\Controller;

use Lrc\Buscrawler\Attribute\RouteAccess;

class UserController
{

    #[RouteAccess(RouteAccess::AUTHENTICATED)]
    public function profile()
    {
        echo '';
    }
}
```

And I pretend to use the canAccess method when resolving the routings, so I can check if that session can acess that route. The way I tried to do is like this:

```php
namespace Lrc\Buscrawler\Service;

use ReflectionMethod;
use Lrc\Buscrawler\Attribute\RouteAccess;

class AccessService
{
    public static function canAccess($session, $controller, $method)
    {
        $con = new $controller();
        $refMethod = new ReflectionMethod($con, $method);
        $attributeRef = $refMethod->getAttributes(RouteAccess::class)[0];
        $attr = $attributeRef->newInstance();
        $attr->canAccess($session);
    }

}
```

I am getting an **Attribute class not found (0)** error at the `$attributeRef->newInstance()`, even though it is imported with use and has passed through the reference to that class in the previous line at `getAttributes(RouteAccess::class)`

The things I have tried already:

- I have done some `var_dump($attributeRef)` to check the content of the variable, and it returned me a correct `object(ReflectionAttribute)#23 (0) { }`
- I have tried the `$attributeRef->getName()` and it correctly returns me the expected value
- I have tried the `$attributeRef->getArguments()` and it also gives me an error of **Attribute class not found (0)**

  - Changing the attributes from `#[RouteAccess(RouteAccess::AUTHENTICATED)]` to `#[RouteAccess(2)]`, solves the problem calling `$attributeRef->getArguments()`, but not at `$attributeRef->newInstance()`

Comment: _"even though it is imported with use"_ `use` doesn't import anything, you still need `include/require/...` statements to import another file.

Comment: @shingo It is all under autoload PSR4, and namespaced correctly

Comment: Sorry for asking, but just so I'm clear, when you say `use ...\Attribute\RouteAccess;`, you are redacting for the sake of putting code on this site, that's not your literal code, right?

Comment: However, the code shown for `RouteAccess` doesn't include a `namespace` either, can you make sure to post that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, updated in the text with full namespacing used

Comment: This is the stacktrace:

500 Internal Server Error
Attribute class "Lrc\Buscrawler\Attribute\RouteAccess" not found (0)
#0 /var/www/html/src/Service/AccessService.php(15): ReflectionAttribute->newInstance()

Comment: Are you sure the autoloader worked properly? Try to manually include the file contains `RouteAccess`.

Comment: @shingo, yes, I have created some dummy class and method to be called from the same way, and it worked fine.

I am using FlightPHP. All routes are redirected to index.php to be resolved there. Since every request goes through there, I only need to put the autoload in index.php

none of my other files has the require autoload as well.

Comment: thanks for help, I have found the error. it was a typo. The namespace was different than folder structure, folder was named Attributes, in the plural

Comment: We actually have a dedicated "Close as a typo" option since these kinds of questions and answers are rarely helpful to future readers. But I'm glad you found your bug!

Comment: i'll see that option then, didnt knew tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo where folder name was not equal to namespace defined for the files.